# Scala Eclipse plugin doesn't show mouse hover documentation

Tags: eclipse, scala, javadoc, scala-ide, scaladoc

I just installed the Scala IDE Eclipse plugin with a fresh install of Eclipse Indigo.  I followed the [getting started youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtkNg4mK4NY) on the scala-ide.org main page on a fresh installation of Indigo. Instead of showing the complete documentation for the String Java class, it shows "type String = String"

I did notice incidentally by looking at the project properties, that in the scala-library.jar and others in the project, under "javadoc location," they show "(None) - non modifiable." I'm not sure if this is the problem, or if the Scala editor gets its documentation somewhere else.

Has anyone else experienced this and/or figured out how to fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: Almost year is past... Any updates or success stories?

Comment: @ArtemIce https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000210 still not fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to the bug that you've raised ([Mouse hover doesn't show documentation](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000571-mouse-hover-doesn-t-show-documentation)), there 
 are the following issues:

1. [Hovering on a type should show its javadoc](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000299-hovering-on-a-type-should-show-its-javadoc)
2. [Javadoc view regression](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000255-javadoc-view-regression)

As you can see, the issue is a real bug, so there aren't any workarounds at the minute. Sorry.

You could always fix it if you like :-)

Comment: I'll wait to be hired by Typesafe :)

Answer (score 0):

So there are updates to this question 
The issues stated above are fixed in the latest release.

[Hovering on type should show fix](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000299-hovering-on-a-type-should-show-its-javadoc/details)

[Scaladoc integration with code completion](https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000210-scaladoc-integration-with-code-completion/details)

Please use the latest release of ScalaIDE(post 3.0.4-211) to work with them